# Which agency issues private pilot certificates?

Tags: faa, icao, student-pilot

With which agency would you apply if you wanted a private pilot certificate? Is it FAA (Federal Aviation Administration), NTSB (National Transportation Safety Board), or ICAO (International Civil Aviation Organization)?

Comment: In which country?

Comment: In general, it would be a country's CAA - Civil Aviation Authority - which goes by different names in different countries. In the US, for example, the CAA is the FAA.

Answer (score 7):

[Here in the USA the FAA is the agency that issues all levels of Pilots Certificates.](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/) However the certificate is not simply applied for, it requires training and the passage of a written, oral, and practical exam. [You can find the current requirements here.](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/private_airplane_acs_6A.pdf)

For reference the [NTSB investigates accidents](https://www.ntsb.gov/Pages/default.aspx) (all transportation accidents for that matter)

And [ICAO is a UN organization that deals with coordinating aviation related maters all over the globe](https://www.icao.int/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you're in the USA and you've undergone training and you're ready to write your exam, so the answer to your question is FAA (Federal Aviation Administration) it's the agency that issues all levels of Pilots Certificates from PPL-ATPL.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! You might like to take the [tour] to find out more about how this site works.